# How can I make RecyclerView partially transparent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I make RecyclerView partially transparent to get effect like this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: That may be very difficult to achieve. I don't think that it is standard in Android. Try simplifying your design to maximise support.

Comment: It's very simple. Just set the Alpha of your layout's background (a greyscale gradient picture) to about 50% (or whichever value you like better). So you'll see it's container background through, with a gradual transition due to the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found solution. Create custom *RecyclerView* and override method:

```
@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0;
}
```

Than just use it in xml layout:

```
<CustomRecycler
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="300dp"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"/>
```